# Copy data from a sheet to another one based on comparison of data in first colomn

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel file with two sheet (Sheet1 and Sheet2). 
In Sheet1 I have data as shown below:
http://i47.tinypic.com/2qulksn.jpg
In Sheet2 I have data as shown below (Not the same number of rows, order of names has changed, and other columns are empty):
http://i48.tinypic.com/15gxkev.jpg

What I would like to do, is compare Sheet2 with Sheet1, looking at the first column, and when the name matches, then copy entire row from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Do nothing when there is no match ie leave New Person as is.

I am sorry I don't know VB to start writing a script you could correct. Thanks in advance for all your replies.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use Vlookup function of excel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. As I had a large sheet and the cell locations in A were not the same, I did this and it worked: =VLOOKUP($A2:A901,Sheet1!A:F,2,0) for A2, =VLOOKUP($A2:A901,Sheet1!A:E,3,0) for A3 ... Where the name in sheet2 doesn't exist in Sheet1, it just returns #N/A. Which is fine with me, unless there is a way to display a 0 instead. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use ISNA function  =IF(ISNA(your VLOOKUP formula),0,your VLOOKUP formula)

Comment: Worked as well! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

No VB script necessary. Try `=vlookup($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$11,column())` in Sheet2!B2.

Breakdown: vlookup( `lookup value with $ on column only so the row updates as you drag down`, `array on sheet1 that you are looking up on - this will change depending on your data table`, `column() will output the column number thereby giving the column in your array you want to output - will only work if the data headings and cell locations are the exact same`)